# can not to connect to my printer on the same access point

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, printer, wireless-access-point

I have a router and an access point setup.
my access point ( engenius ecb 300) which is located at the second floor is utp-wired to my router  which is located at the first floor.

My printer is in the room next to the access point at the second floor, connected via wifi to the access point.

now my laptop is also in a room next to the access point at the second floor, also connected via wifi to the access point

Now somehow I can't connect from my laptop to my printer. I can ping every other device which is utp-wired to my router (raspberry pi's, pc's) but not to the printer on the same access point.

From any other computer (which are all utp-wired to the router) I can access the printer.

So the only laptop which is giving me trouble is the one which is (wifi) connected to the same access point.

Is this somehow by design?

Comment: do you have a feature called 'client isolation' or 'ap isolation' (or anything with the word isolation) in it enabed on the AP? client isolation is great for wifi in places like coffee shops, because it keeps differant users from seeing eachother and prevents the guy in the corner from sniffing your unencrypted traffic, but it would also prevent you from accessing the printer.

Comment: Just FYI, client isolation won't stop anyone on the same wireless network from sniffing your traffic. It's still being broadcast wirelessly, so everyone can see it.

Comment: I have 2 checkboxes, labeled SSID and STA, which are in the section: 'security, separate:'. The helpfiles says: "Separating the SSID from each other (or use of STA) prevents communication and data sharing between wireless stations associated with the SSIDs." It sounds like what you are saying, but i'm not sure about the SSID and STA checkbox (and what STA means). My access point can send signal in 4 different SSID's (the help says: "Select the number of SSID’s (Wireless Network names) you would like (up to 4).")

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where I couldn't print while wirelessly connected to the same access point that my wireless printer was connected to.  I was using two APs and the one that I was having problems with was a Linksys Smart Wi-Fi.

SOLVED - The problem turned out to be that I had my "guest network" turned off.  I guess by doing this, the router defaults to a network isolation mode which prevents one wifi device from talking directly to another wifi device.  All is well now after hours of experimenting with AP settings and printer settings.